# Huge Numpy list - How to get n digit?

Tags: python, digits

Currently i have a huge database of randomly generated numbers in numpy.

```
array([62051180209, 87882444506, 49821030805, ..., 54840854303,
       21222836608, 24070750502])
```

Now i want to check how many nunmbers have for ex. nunmber 05, 15 digits on position 3 and 4. (ex. 62-05-1180209, like first on my list)

I would like to check how many numberx have other digits in other position. Like position 5, 6. 1st on my list have number 11 for example.

Comment: Did converting everything to strings take too long, and you're looking for a faster solution, or are you saying you don't know how to do this at all?

Comment: Honestly i'm novice in python. So at the moment don't have idea how to do this. I thought maybe there is a command to do this, but i was searching and i didn't find anything.

Comment: try converting numbers to string and then get the digits by index and check in a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Random Davis already suggested, this might work:

```
import numpy as np
mylist = np.array([62011180209, 87882444506, 49821030805, 54840854303,21222836608, 24070750502])

def get_matches(mylist, start, end, value):
    value = str(value)
    return [str(i)[start:end+1]==value  for i in mylist]

get_matches(mylist, start=3, end=4, value=11)
```

For that list this delivers the following result:

```
[True, False, False, False, False, False]
```

If multiple choices should be considered, then with a naive approach, the above function can be rewritten as follows:

```
def get_matches_multichoice(mylist, start, end, valuelist):
    valuelist = [str(value) for value in valuelist]
    return [str(i)[start:end+1] in valuelist  for i in mylist]
```

Calling is for the above data example:

```
print (get_matches_multichoice(mylist, start=3, end=5, valuelist=np.array([111, 824, 408])) )
```

then returns:

```
[True, True, False, True, False, False]
```

Comment: This is obviously the simplest approach. As discussed by Marat, there is a very elegant solution which uses the original numeric values. Using %timeit cell magic for the example array above I'm getting 4.29 µs for the pure numeric approach vs. 4.83 µs for the string conversion approach.

Comment: Is it possible to check multiple values at the same time? For example i want to check if digit on place 10 is equal 0 or 2 or 4 or 6 or 8? get_matches(mylist, start=10, end=10, value=?).count(True). Counting works with single value. I tried to put different values like (0,2...) or [0,2] but it dosen't work.

Comment: Yes. By replacing `value = str(value)` with  `valuelist = [str(value) for value in valuelist]` and the function should return the folllowing: `return [str(i)[start:end+1] in valuelist  for i in mylist]`

Comment: `valuelist` should be a list or array of your desired possibilities e.g. in your example [0,2,4,6,8]. The rest of the function parameters should be the same.

Comment: Yes! it works, thank you very much! :) If may i ask. Is there a easy way to store this number or values counted as True with variable?

Comment: Oh nvm it was easier than i thought. Used adeed variable = get_matches... Thank You once again!

Comment: Thanks, great, to hear :-) As mentioned above, for efficiency and better speed you can also try adopting the approach of Marat.

Answer (score 2):

Operations on strings take a lot more CPU and RAM than integers. It is A LOT faster to use integer math instead:

```
def get_matches(array, start, end, value): 
    return np.remainder(array // 10**start, 10**(end-start)) == value
```

Explained:

- `array // 10**start` drops `start` digits at the end, using whole number division
- `np.remainder` drops everything except `end-start` trailing digits
- `== value` checks if the value matches. Note that to check if two digits are 05, value should be just 5.

Comment: The only problem is this goes backwards instead of forwards, so `start` and `end` count from the least-significant digit instead of the most-significant. Otherwise, much better strategy than converting to strings and iterating on the numpy array.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi yes. Also it's trivial to reverse this logic given the length of generated numbers

Comment: Probably not so trivial when the numbers don't all have the same length, but doable nonetheless.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi in general case, it would be true. Here we're dealing with a random number generator, which are expected to produce numbers in a known range, which defines the max length